# Spark iteration logic to write the dataset filtered by date to parquet format failing OOM

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, pyspark

I have a scenario where i have dataset with date column and later i use the dataset in iteration to save the dataset into multiple partition files in parquet format. I do iterate the date list and while writing to parquet format with that date partition folder i do filter the dataset with date.

I was able to write for certain iterations but after that its failing with Spark out of memory exceptions.

Whats the best way to optimise this to persist the data with OOM.

```
dataset = dataset with some transformations
for date in date-list
   pd.write_part_file("part-data-file", dataset.filter(archive_date==date))
```

The code looks like above.

Comment: could you share your code?

Comment: You may wanna try to `dataset.repartition(n)` to a higher number `n` of partitions before the loop.

Comment: @mazaneicha There is one post about this issue which has similar iteration to write multiple partitions in parquet format. Trying to understand this. I can think of repartition as well.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8890

Comment: Hope you're not using Spark 1.5.

Comment: No, I am using spark 2 version

Comment: @mazaneicha dataset.repartition(column date) is taking longer time to execute.

Comment: Well... you'll have to decide whats better -- OOM and a crash or successful execution but over longer time. Or, pay more to increase executor memory, do not repartition and succeed in shorter time.